# How can I correct a Free Fillable Forms reported error about being someone's dependent?

Tags: united-states, stimulus

It says that I am not eligible for the stimulus check because I am listed as someone's dependent. This is not correct — I am single, have no dependents and am NOT listed on any one else's return as a dependent.

Comment: How old are you? Are you a student? Do you live with parents/ step parents/ other adults? I ask because the real question is are you *eligible* to be someone’s dependent?

Comment: "It says that I am not eligible for the stimulus check" Which place is saying that?

Comment: It might be fraud. That is, someone else (a total stranger) might have used your SSN to fraudulently claim that you were their dependent. Here is some IRS info about a similar dependent fraud situation. It's not exactly the same, but it is a place to start. https://www.irs.gov/identity-theft-fraud-scams/identity-theft-dependents

Comment: Does it say that you're listed as someone's dependent or does it say that you could be claimed as someone's dependent. AFAIK they don't check with the IRS before letting you fill out forms. Just because you're not listed on someone's tax return doesn't mean that you couldn't be listed as someone's dependent